# Parental leave - what are my rights

Tags: leave-of-absence

I want to take parental leave, but i'd prefer that co-workers don't know about my personal stuff, i.e. i'd just tell them i'm taking a leave of absence, i'm male so i wont show ;)

do i have rights over management not to disclose this information to my co-workers?  i.e. they can only say i'm taking time off?

Comment: This is truly bizarre. You feel entitled to time off, as a result of your fatherhood, but you don't want it to be publicly known. I think it used to be the reverse.

Comment: Related Question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19709/how-much-personal-information-am-i-obligated-to-share-with-my-manager

Comment: This sort of question does not really work well on a Q&A site.  There is missing information (Where are you, what are you wanting to accomplish, how much time are you looking to take off, what is it you do not understand about your company policy?)  For that reason I have voted to put this quesiton on hold.  I think it could be a good question but we do not really have anywhere near the information we need to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the comment, this may depend on where you work.  That said, you absolutely have the right to say to your boss "I want parental leave - I'd rather not discuss this with my co-workers.  Is it all right if we describe it as annual leave?"

Personally, I think it's fine to make that request - but accepting it is a different matter.  Suppose one of your co-workers comes up to your boss and says

- Why is Dave allowed so much time off?  I've been here longer, I should get more holiday!
- Has Dave been placed on administrative leave? What did he do?!
- Is Dave ill?  Should we get a card and flowers?
- Was Dave fired?  Should we start looking for a replacement?
- I heard a rumour that Dave's on study leave - how do I apply for that?
- Where's Dave?

Ultimately, your personal life is your own business.  As a manager, I would certainly respect your privacy - but it could become complex without a suitable "cover story."

If I were you, I'd accept the fact that your co-workers may wish to buy you a cake and give you a "congratulations" card.